# MySQL Tables Could Not Be Read

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using Appserv for local MySQL hosting. I had to reset my computer. I forgot to make backup for MySQL database and used Win 10 reset feature. So it removed all the applications but not personal files. After resetting my pc, I set up the Appserv again. I got into phpMyAdmin. On the left side, I can see all of the tables. But when i click on them, I'm having an error message "*#1146 - Table 'database.table' doesn't exist*". So i only have the MySQL data files which has database's .frm and .ibd files.
My question is, can i recover tables with these .frm and .ibd files?

Note: ib_logfile and ibdata files are overwrited after setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on Google I found an article that may help you but bear that in mind that once you erase something permanently by mistake or otherwise and if you haven't made the appropriate backups then I am sorry to say that whatever you do to try and resurrect it won't work.

Nevertheless, try out the link below and let me know of your progress:

http://www.voxteneo.com/restoring-tables-mysql-database-frm-ibd-files-available/

Comment: I've searched a lot but did not mind to search by file extentions. Thanks a lot. I'll git it a try.